# Mobile menu icons don't hide after resize to desktop

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

So here's my site: https://www.vargdesign.net/

When sizing the window < 1024px, the mobile css will take over showing the mobile menu icons. When the menu is opened and the window resize back to desktop (> 1024px), the menu icons don't hide anymore. I've tried several different ways of writing the script in jQuery for it but I haven't found a solution in 3 hours.

The website is based on WordPress and I created the theme myself.

PHP snippet:

```
<header>
  <div class="head">
    <?php the_custom_logo(); ?>
    <div class="menu-toggle">
      <i id="menu-open" class="fas fa-bars"></i>
      <i id="menu-close" class="fas fa-times"></i>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location'=>'main')); ?>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Script:

```
// add mobile menu toggle
function menu_toggle() {
  var navToggle = 1;
  // open menu on click
  function menu_open() {
    $('#menu-open').hide();
    $('#menu-close').show();
    $('nav').addClass('pull-down');
    var navToggle = 2;
    // lock scroll position, but retain settings for later
    var scrollPosition = [
      self.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft || document.body.scrollLeft,
      self.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop
    ];
    var html = jQuery('html');
    html.data('scroll-position', scrollPosition);
    html.data('previous-overflow', html.css('overflow'));
    html.css('overflow', 'hidden');
    window.scrollTo(scrollPosition[0], scrollPosition[1]);
  }
  if (navToggle = 1) {
    $('#menu-open').click(menu_open);
  }
  // close menu on click
  function menu_close() {
    $('#menu-close').hide();
    $('#menu-open').show();
    $('nav').removeClass('pull-down');
    var navToggle = 1;
    // unlock scroll position
    var html = jQuery('html');
    var scrollPosition = html.data('scroll-position');
    html.css('overflow', html.data('previous-overflow'));
    window.scrollTo(scrollPosition[0], scrollPosition[1]);
  }
  if (navToggle = 2) {
    $('#menu-close, .content').click(menu_close);
  }
}

$(document).ready(menu_toggle);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest solution would be to just write some CSS to ensure they will be hidden when the viewport width is greater than or equal to 1024px, e.g.:

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
   .menu-toggle + nav {
      display: none;
   }
}
```

Comment: Leaving out the "+ nav" part and it works. I tried using it before, but realized now that I have to put it behind the mobile media query and not before it. Thanks.

Comment: Sure! In that case, the menu icons stay but the toggle button hides instead. By getting the order of the media queries right, you are using [precedence](https://css-tricks.com/precedence-css-order-css-matters/) - it is also possible to use [specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/), e.g. `.head > .menu-toggle { display: none; }`, so that you can use any order you prefer. Glad you reached a solution :)